# How to check for the ESD protection of the capacitors

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, esd, electrostatic

I have this circuit

[image]

I need to check whether my input capacitors C0001-c0004 are protected for ESD events.

My ESD pulse spec: +/-8kV, 2kohms & 330pF. I have taken 130% of this +8kV as my ESD pulse for the worst case calculations.

I am performing the calculations as per this Article - [Capacitor as ESD Protection](http://electronicsbeliever.com/capacitor-as-esd-protection/)

So, in accordance with the above article,

My calculations are below:

[image]

According to the above calculations, my questions :

1. Since the required capacitance is more than the actual capacitance present in the above calculation, does this mean, I should increase the input capacitor capacitance value? Or what does it mean?
2. So, after the ESD event, the capacitors will help to clamp the voltage to 72.512V approx. , & it will be present at Input_P node and will damage the Q0002 transistor, since Q0002 Vce(max) is only 45V. Since, 72.512V > 45V, won't this 72.512 damage the transistor and the other downstream components and also components connected on the Input_P rail?

So, should I focus on the capacitor capacitance value for the ESD calculations or should I focus on the ESD Clamp voltage ? I am confused. Please tell me how to validate my design using the calculation.

Comment: Can you put a varistor on the input?

Comment: Why have you chosen the maximum allowable clamp voltage to be 70 volts when you know your downstream circuit is only capable of withstanding 45 volts? Where did the table come from?

Comment: My downstream circuit is only a set of transistors whose Vce(max) is 45V. And I myself calculated that table

Comment: @winny, I don't think I can add a varistor on the input

Comment: Change the 70 volts to 45 volts and recalculate is my advice. Take note that the formulas are still enacting the Q=CV rule I mentioned in answer a few months ago.